# Drop/delete from database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

```
 $dialogContent.dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: "Edit - " + calEvent.title,
    close: function() {
       $dialogContent.dialog("destroy");
       $dialogContent.hide();
       $('#calendar').weekCalendar("removeUnsavedEvents");
    },
    buttons: {
       save : function() {

          calEvent.start = new Date(startField.val());
          calEvent.end = new Date(endField.val());
          calEvent.title = titleField.val();
          calEvent.body = bodyField.val();

          $calendar.weekCalendar("updateEvent", calEvent);
          $dialogContent.dialog("close");
       },
       "delete" : function() {
          $calendar.weekCalendar("removeEvent", calEvent.id);
          $dialogContent.dialog("close");
       },
       cancel : function() {
          $dialogContent.dialog("close");
       }
    }
 }).show();
```

I want to make `"delete" : function() {` drop it from database. Im connecting true DB.php to my database.

How can i fix that ?

Comment: You'll need to use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to send a request to your PHP file which will in turn delete the correct row from your database table.

Comment: Im not that good with AJAX, json java etc. what code will be help me out to DROP line from database. Can you help me out

Comment: AJAX... It's what will do what you are after

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger an AJAX request inside your delete function. If you go to the following page it will explain how to use it. It will give you the result you're after.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/